# File upload button

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to have a file upload button for a `models.ImageField`. However, I don't want it to render with `choose file:no file chosen`. Instead, I would like a file upload button that pops up a select file button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all django related but the easiest way to do it is to add a `hidden` attribute to your input then style it accordingly:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" hidden/>
<label for="upload">Choose file</label>
```

```
label{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: indigo;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @haduki. I will try that out. Question, what is 'for='' used for? I seen that in several HTML/CSS examples and have not yet figured that out.

Comment: When used together with the `label` element, the `for` attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

When used together with the `output` element, the `for` attribute specifies the relationship between the result of the calculation, and the elements used in the calculation.